# Trouble using py2exe

Tags: python-2.7, py2exe

When i write this command in CMD

```
python.exe C:\Users\osman\Desktop\setup.py c:\py2exe
```

Then it says that unable to import py2exe.
I don't understand what to do now.

please help.

Comment: Do you have the py2exe library installed?  What version of Python are you using?  What OS are you running?

Comment: Yes i have python installed.

Comment: My version is python27

Comment: But do you have `py2exe` installed? It's not in the standard library.

Comment: i have installed py2exe .

Comment: Where exactly should i put it in.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are running on Windows since you are using python.exe.

First, make sure you installed python correctly, including configure the system path. Then in CMD you should be able to type 'python' and run directly.

Then make sure you installed py2exe correctly.
When you install, it will find your python path automatically.

So if you have the question "Where exactly should I put it in", it probably means you didn't install it correctly.

After finish installing, you can run the command:

python C:\Users\osman\Desktop\setup.py py2exe